# Properties should not return arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

Yes, I know this has been discussed many times before, and I read all the posts and comments regarding this question, but still can't seem to understand something.

One of the options that MSDN offers to solve this violation, is by returning a *collection* (or an *interface* which is implemented by a *collection*) when accessing the property, however clearly it *does not solve the problem* because most collections are not immutable and can also be changed.

Another possibility I've seen in the answers and comments to this question is to encapsulate the array with a `ReadOnlyCollection` and return it or a base interface of it(like `IReadOnlyCollection`), but I don't understand how this solves the performance issue.

If at any time the property is referenced it needs to *allocate memory* for a new `ReadOnlyCollection` that encapsulates the array, so what is the difference (in a manner of performance issues, not editing the array/collection) than simply returning a copy of the original array?

Moreover, ReadOnlyCollection has only one constructor with `IList` argument so there's a need to wrap the array with a list prior to creating it.

If I intentionally want to work with an array inside my class (not as immutable collection), is the performance better when I allocate new memory for a `ReadOnlyCollection` and encapsulate my array with it instead of returning a copy of the array?

Please clarify this.

Comment: Who said it was anything to do with performance?

Comment: A must read article by Eric on arrays - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx

Comment: Article by Eric is no longer accessible. Dec 2022

Answer (score 32):

> If at any time the property is referenced it needs to allocate memory for a new ReadOnlyCollection that encapsulates the array, so what is the difference (in a manner of performance issues, not editing the array/collection) than simply returning a copy of the original array?

A `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` *wraps* a collection - it doesn't *copy* the collection.

Consider:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly int[] array; // Initialized in constructor

    public IReadOnlyList<int> Array => array.ToArray(); // Copy
    public IReadOnlyList<int> Wrapper => new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(array); // Wrap
}
```

Imagine your array contains a million entries. Consider the amount of work that the `Array` property has to do - it's got to take a copy of all million entries. Consider the amount of work that the `Wrapper` property has to do - it's got to create an object which just contains a reference.

Additionally, if you don't mind a small extra memory hit, you can do it once instead:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly int[] array; // Initialized in constructor
    private readonly IReadOnlyList<int> Wrapper { get; }

    public Foo(...)
    {
        array = ...;
        Wrapper = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(array);
    }
}
```

Now accessing the `Wrapper` property doesn't involve any allocation at all - it doesn't matter if *all* callers see the same wrapper, because they can't mutate it.

Answer (score 4):

You have no need to *copy* an array, just *return* it as `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`:

```
  public class MyClass {
    private int[] myArray = ...

    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> MyArray {
      get {
        return myArray;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I just tested nearly identical code, because it seemed some obvious (so maybe I was missing something). Maybe the worry is that someone will forcibly cast the IReadOnlyColelction to an array and modify it then? I wouldn't worry about it though, as if someone wants to, he can use reflection to mess with private field directly...

Comment: That's no good if the caller casts back to `int[]` (or just `IList<int>`) and then mutates it. It might be okay for an internal API, but I wouldn't do it in a public API, where other code might want to *depend* on the contents not being mutated.

Comment: How come this trick works? where in the inheritance tree does int[] inherit from IReadOnlyCollection<int>? clearly it works but how is this casting possible? where is it defined?